# Latex tables appearing in my journal paper's references

Tags: latex

I'm using the Springer latex template for my journal paper, which is a two-column template.

To describe the table I'm using `\begin{table*}...\end{table*}`, but I can't control the position.

As a result, I find that the tables are placed in my references, as shown below.

[image: Rendered output]

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Please edit your question and include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've reformatted your question to be a bit more readable, and embedded the screenshot. To help out answerers I think you should provide a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

Try `\clearpage` before the reference section